# Trouble Understanding MLMultiArray Arguments

Tags: ios, coreml

I am looking at some CoreML code in iOS which contains the following line. This has something to do with CoreML returning images and the app displaying images. But I am not exactly sure what this line does.

```
 let array = try? MLMultiArray(shape: [1] as [NSNumber], dataType: .double)
                array?[0] = 1.0
```

What does the above code mean?

Answer (score 0):

It creates an MLMultiArray object containing a single value that is 1.0 (a Double).